# Do I have to include user_id on every table I wanna access with Devise gem?(Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise gem on rails for authentication and I have everything set up already and working. What I did not understand from the documentation is if I needed to add user_id field to every table using this gem. I have:

```
users table 
candidates table
activities_candidates table
candidates_languages table
languages table
and some others like this
```

In which tables I need to include a user_id field???. Cause until now I was using the candidate_id as a foreign key for the tables I needed to have a relation, should I change it now to use the user_id instead of the candidate_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change it, just set up devise to work with the candidate model, if that's what you want.  You can use whatever name for the user account you like.  Check out the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models).

But, if you're new to Rails, using `user` all over is a common way to go.

Comment: Yes, I want that and I have another model made for institutions with its intermmediate tables. In this case should I put the user_id only in the candidates and institutions tables?. Can you give some more detail on how to accomplish this? I read the documentation but it's not clear enough on some points....If you could give me just some hints to get started

Comment: In the link you provided only explain if you want to add an additional admin model, but do not say anything about using the same user that it's in the Users table to have access to all the website wout having to depend on user_id

Comment: The foreign keys on the other tables is fine to leave alone. You don't need to add any other keys or change the names if it's working.  All devise needs is the main table (user or candidate).  The link is just how you would add devise for any model - not necessarily multiple.

Comment: but I have a Candidate model and a Company model, they both log in into the system as users......How do I do in this case?....

Comment: A company is a type of user?  Or do you have many people that belong to a company?

Comment: it's a kind of user, there are two kind, candidate and company, and both tables are related to the user table

Comment: So, they have user_id foreign keys on them?  user is the owner or it's a join table?  If so, they are not users.  Devise would only apply to users table.  If they are a distinct user in your app (like an admin might be) then you would configure devise for each table.

Comment: Both the company table and the Candidate table have user_id as a foreign key to the user table. They are different type of users, same attributes but they need to have some distinction in order for them to be redirected properly to different sites and actions.....

Comment: They probably don't need a way to authenticate.  Authenticating the actual user and providing access to the candidate object and company based on user's relationship to the object is what you really want.  Good luck

Comment: That's exactly what I did...I added a usertype to the user table and both candidates and companies are tied to the user table. At the moment of signing up you specify if you are a company or not. When you log in it checks the type_user_id on the user table and redirects him to the candidate controller or to the company controller. Thank you very much my friend!

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to include `user_id` on each table.

`user_id` is a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) -- if you included it in all your other tables, it suggests an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) (your `User` model shouldn't exist).

The *right* way to fix it is to use Devise on your `Candidate` model:

---

**Devise**

Devise supports using [any model](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models) you want:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :candidates

#app/models/candidate.rb
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable

    #Associations
    has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
    ...
end
```

You'll have to change your `candidates` table to include the `devise` functionality (you can just rename your `users` table to `candidates` & drop the current table, or copy the column structure with a migration).

--

**Foreign Keys**

The other way to resolve it is to change the `foreign_key` switch for your associations (on the `User` model):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :languages, join_table: :candidate_languages, foreign_key: :candidate_id
   has_and_belongs_to_many :activities, join_table: :activities_candidates, foreign_key: :candidate_id
end
```

You'd basically have to add all the associations for the `Candidate` model, and define their `foreign key`s explicitly. And, yes, it will be as much work as it sounds.

As can be seen by the above code, it's glaringly obvious you should just replace the `User` model with `Candidate`.